# Use a runtime field in decay function elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

In Elastic I am using a runtime field to calculate a personal price based on user input. The field is defined as a 'double' type and has a Painless script to calculate the price. The output is fine and I can then sort by this runtime field, so up until now it works. But I also need to use a decay function on it. This decay function works for all other (numeric) fields, but using it on the runtime field it throws this error:

```
`[parsing_exception] field [price] is of type [org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DoubleScriptFieldType@30880a5d], but only numeric types are supported.`
```

A simplified version of my compiled query is:

```
    {
    "from": 0,
    "size": 500,
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "range": {
                                "price": {
                                    "gte": "90.00",
                                    "lte": "220.00"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "functions": [
                {
                    "linear": {
                        "price": {
                            "origin": "150.00",
                            "scale": 10,
                            "offset": "50.00",
                            "decay": 0.75
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "script_score": {
                        "script": "0"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "boost_mode": "sum",
            "score_mode": "first"
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "_score": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        },
        {
            "price": {
                "order": "asc"
            }
        }
    ],
    "_source": {
        "include": [],
        "exclude": []
    },
    "fields": [
        "price"
    ],
    "runtime_mappings": {
        "price": {
            "type": "double",
            "script": {
                "source": 
                    "def incomeTaxPercentage = params['settings'].income_tax_percentage; def price = (incomeTaxPercentage / 100) * 200; emit(price > 0 ? price : 0.00);",
                "params": {
                    "settings": {
                        "income_tax_percentage": 37.5
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried this in Elasticsearch v 8.2.0 and I've tried to define other types in the runtime field, and also tried to put it in the mapping as a float before overriding with the runtime field. And I also attempted to use the script_score function instead, which throws a similar error.

So my question is if I'm doing something wrong/missing something, or this is simply not (yet) supported by elastic?

Comment: Did u manage to find a solution? I'm also facing the same issue. As I'm trying a POC before requesting any mapping changes...

Comment: I didn't unfortunately.. Tried everything I could think of, and I don't easily draw the conclusion something is not possible but here I had to.

Comment: I managed it with a script function score where you can call the decay function with a painless script

Comment: see here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-score-query.html#decay-functions-numeric-fields